CiviMobile does not show street address in reserved respondents or interviewed or GOTV
I am logged in as administrator. On Civimobile when I bring up a list of respondents to interview/survey I get a long list of the correct names, but the street address is not shown. I can click on any name and then the street address is shown on the next page.
I am using this for door to door canvassing and cannot see how to display the street address in the long list of reserved respondents.
When I log into CRM on my laptop, the street address shows fine.

Picture attached from the CiviMobile documentation is what I am trying to achieve.
